# Динамическое выделение памяти, перегрузка операторов

Tags: c++, new

Возник такой вопрос, разбираю тему из книги Герберта Шилдта по С++, тема "Перегрузка операторов". В данном примере перегрузка оператора =, никак не пойму в конструкторе вот эту конструкцию "s = new char('\0');", разве здесь не произойдет утечка памяти, так при инициализации конструктора мы *s инициализируем(s = new char('\0');), а затем в методе "void sample::set(char *str)" мы для *s перевыделяем память не освободив при этом s = new char('\0');. Собственно вопрос, что здесь вообще происходит.))

```
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class sample {
    char *s;
public:
    sample(); // normal constructor
    sample(const sample &ob); // copy constructor
    ~sample( ) {
        if(s) delete [] s;
        cout << "Freeing s\n";
    }
    void show() {
        cout << s << "\n";
    }
    void set(char *str);
    sample &operator=(const sample &ob); // overload assignment
};

// Normal constructor.
sample::sample()
{
    s = new char('\0'); // s points to a null string.
}

// Copy constructor.
sample::sample(const sample &ob)
{
    s = new char[strlen(ob.s)+1];
    strcpy(s, ob.s);
}

// Load a string.
void sample::set(char *str)
{
    s = new char[strlen(str)+1];
    strcpy(s, str);
}

// Overload assignment operator.
sample &sample::operator=(const sample &ob)
{
/* If the target memory is not large enough
then allocate new memory. */
    if(strlen(ob.s) > strlen(s)) {
        delete [] s;
        s = new char[strlen(ob.s)+1];
    }
    strcpy(s, ob.s);
    return *this;
}

// Return an object of type sample.
sample input()
{
    char instr[80];
    sample str;
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    cin >> instr;
    str.set(instr);
    return str;
}

int main() {
    sample ob;

    ob = input();
    ob.show();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Произойдет. Пример составлен безобразно. Читайте книги поновее.

Comment: я думал это опечатка, посмотрел книгу в оригинале на английском, тоже самое написано

Comment: Недоработка переводчика - надо было исправить автора :)